# How to apply materialDesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode="Accent" in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I have been trying to render a group box dynamically in code behind for a few days using MaterialDesign for WPF. With some help I received in another StackOverflow question, I was able to render it using material design style with the line below:

`childDef.Style = Application.Current.FindResource("MaterialDesignGroupBox") as Style;`

What I am trying to achieve is to render it using the defined material design accent color of the application and not the primary color which is the default color for the resource "MaterialDesignGroupBox". In Material Design's WPF demo project this is how they do it in xaml:

```
<smtx:XamlDisplay Key="groupbox_4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <GroupBox Header="Accent Header" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignGroupBox}" Margin="16" materialDesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode="Accent">
        <TextBlock>My Content</TextBlock>
    </GroupBox>
</smtx:XamlDisplay>
```

So, what I'm essentially trying to do and I have been unable to figure out how to so far is how apply **materialDesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode="Accent"** in code behind. I thank anyone in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `GroupBox` style (MaterialDesignGroupBox) [uses an attached property](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.GroupBox.xaml#L30) to control the Mode of its internal `ColorZone`. You can set attached properties in the code behind like this:

```
GroupBox groupBox = ...;
MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.ColorZoneAssist.SetMode(groupBox, ColorZoneMode.Accent);
```

Comment: Kevin B thank you sir. This is the correct answer. I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote it, but will do that once I do with all the questions I have posted and received answers.